# Looping through all files in a directory in R

Tags: r, matlab

It's my first time using R, and I just need to input a package with some files and save the outputs in some other files. I have a directory in which there are some files with ".pdb" file extensions. I need to go through each of these files in a for loop, apply some functions, and save the output of each ,which is a matrix, in a file that I could later use in Matlab.

These are the functions that I wish to apply to each of the .pdb files.

```
p=extractPDB("1HXH.pdb")
cm<-build.contacts(n=p$lca,xyz=p$coords,cuts=169)$cm
```

cm is the output matrix which I want to save in a  file to be later used in Matlab.

Comment: What have you already tried? Why did it not work? Start small: how would you handle one file? How do you export it? If you can do that, see how you can find all files in your directory (hint: `list.files`) and repeat your actions.

Comment: If you `.pdb` file are `Protein Data Bank` you can open them directly in MatLab with the [readpdb](http://it.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/pdbread.html) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping over files with a certain extension is easy. Actually you loop over the filenames.

1. get a list of all files in the directory
2. get only files ending in pdb
3. run a loop over the names

You might have to change the working directory using `setwd`

```
all.files <- list.files()
my.files <- grep(".*pdb", all_files, value=T)
for(i in my_files){
  # do your operations here
  p=extractPDB("1HXH.pdb")
  cm<-build.contacts(n=p$lca,xyz=p$coords,cuts=169)$cm
  # save
  output.filename <- gsub("(.*?).pdb", "\\1.csv", i)
  write.table(cm, output.filename)
}
```

For saving the Files there are many options, for reading the file in matlab it's probably the best to save the matrices as csv-file. Look into the documentation of `write.table` and adjust the parameters so it's convinient for reading.