# Looping through all files: "missForest" package in R

Tags: r, loops, csv

**Search results for the problem:**
However I might not apply the solutions correctly.

1. [Which is the best method to apply a script repetitively to n .csv files in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799096/which-is-the-best-method-to-apply-a-script-repetitively-to-n-csv-files-in-r)
2. [Looping through all files in directory in R, applying multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958516/looping-through-all-files-in-directory-in-r-applying-multiple-commands)
3. [Looping through all files in a directory in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498595/looping-through-all-files-in-a-directory-in-r)

**My Case**
I have a folder with hundreds of csv files. I need to run "missForest" package in R to impute missing values.
If I run the package for the files one by one I have to do the following:

```
##change the file name
G1344108 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)

##run missForest with default settings
G1344108.Forest <- missForest(G1344108, verbose = TRUE, maxiter = 5)

##save the imputed data matrix using filename$ximp 
write.csv(G1344108.Forest$ximp, file = 'G1344108_output.csv')
```

**Question**
How to loop through the files in a folder?

I run the code in this way:

```
   all.files <- list.files()
   my.files <- grep(".*csv", all_files, value=T)
            for(i in my.files){
    # do your operations here
    G1344108.Forest <- missForest(G1344108, verbose = TRUE, maxiter = 5)
    # save
    output.filename <- gsub("(.*?).csv", "\\1.csv", i)
    write.table(G1344108.Forest$ximp, output.filename)
}
```

and it reurns me these following errors:

```
Error in grep(".*csv", all_files, value = T) : 
  object 'all_files' not found
Error: object 'my.files' not found
```

Comment: Which of those solutions did you attempt to use? They don't use `file.choose()`. Did you make any attempt to adapt those answers to your problem? If so, can you show exactly were you were having a problem?

Comment: I tried the 2nd & 3rd. I use file.choose() when I want to run the code for the files one by one. #2 returns me some errors like Error: object 'my_files' not found! I just replaced my code with others codes and I deleted the things like file.choose().
#3 solution returns me this:
Ng.output <- missForest(my.files, verbose = TRUE, maxiter = 5)
Error in apply(is.na(xmis), 2, sum) : dim(X) must have a positive length
> write.csv(Ng.output$ximp, file = "Ng.output.csv")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'Ng.output' not found

Comment: Show the code you actually ran in your question (not a comment). Give specific error messages.

Comment: It would appear `list.files` and a `for` loop or `lapply`/`sapply` is what you want. This is exactly what is offered in answers for all three questions you link to. You're on the right track.

Comment: I've edited my post.